# Sufficient statistics from exponential distributions with different means

Tags: self-study, estimation, sufficient-statistics

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent exponential random variables with means $\theta$ and  $2\theta$ respectively, then show that $X  + 2Y$ is sufficient for $\theta$.

I know how to find sufficient statistics when sampling is done from same density, i.e. for example say $X$ and $Y$ are both iid from $\exp(1/\theta)$. Please suggest how to go with this one.

Comment: Use the factorization theorem

Comment: @Taylor isn't factorization theorem only works with same  density case  ?

Comment: Apply the factorization theorem to the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ or show directly that the density of $\left( X, Y \right) \mid \left( X+2Y \right)$ is independent of $\theta$.

Comment: how to get the probability of intersection ?( i.e$ (X,Y) $ ∩ $X+2Y$)

Comment: @ANUJNAIN Just get the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ and use Neyman's factorization theorem; see, for example, https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/283/.

Comment: @ANUJNAIN If you insist on doing it using the definition, see https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=5PRLUho-YYgC&lpg=PP1&dq=sufficient%20jay%20devore&pg=PA361#v=onepage&q&f=false.

Comment: @Xi'an You wrote "$X\sim \theta\exp\{-\theta x\}\quad Y\sim2\theta\exp\{-2\theta y\}$". But the question said the _means_ are $\theta$ and $2\theta.$ So you need $\exp(-x/\theta)/\theta,$ etc. $\qquad$

Comment: @Xi'an : Yes, but if I had written a comment like yours, I would have mentioned that.

Answer (score 3):

If the means are $\theta$ and $2\theta$ then the joint density is
\begin{align}
f_{X,Y} (u,v) & = e^{-u/\theta} e^{-v/(2\theta)} \times \text{constant} \quad \text{for } u,v\ge0 \\[8pt]
& = e^{-(2u+v)/(2\theta)} \times\text{constant}.
\end{align}
Fisher's factorization theorem then implies that $2X+Y$ (not $X+2Y$) is sufficient for $\theta.$ (The second factor, as often happens, is $1$ in this case.)

On the other hand, if $\theta$ and $2\theta$ are the intensities, also called rates, rather than the means, then $X+2Y$ is sufficient.

Comment: The 'second factor' is the indicator $1_{u,v>0}$ to be precise.

Comment: @StubbornAtom : Except it was given at the outset that $u,v>0.$ We're working only within that space.